# Swift Sorting struct by ordering from another struct

Tags: swift

I have 2 structs (game,otGame) that contains a NSString property called [cod]. 
I try to give the second structure the same order as the first one where [cod] is the same and add the surplus to the queue.

```
game = [cod("001234"),cod("001111"),cod("002222"),cod("005555")]
otGame = [cod("002222"),cod("005555"),cod("001111")]

struct game {
    var cod: NSString
    var des: Float?
}

struct otGame {
    var cod: NSString
    var sor: Float?
}
```

i expect the output of otGame to be

```
[cod("001111"),cod("002222"),cod("005555"),cod("001234")]
```

Comment: Why `NSString`? And according to the naming convention struct names start with a capital letter. And `otGame` contains only 3 items but in the result 4

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
struct Game {
    var cod: String
    var des: Float?
}

struct OtGame {
    var cod: String
    var sor: Float?
}

let games = [Game(cod: "001234", des: nil),
             Game(cod: "001111", des: nil),
             Game(cod:"002222", des: nil),
             Game(cod:"005555", des: nil)]
var otGames = [OtGame(cod: "002222", sor: nil),
               OtGame(cod: "005555", sor: nil),
               OtGame(cod: "001111", sor: nil)]

//Sort otGames based on indexes of games
otGames.sort { (o1, o2) -> Bool in
    if let index1 = games.firstIndex(where: {$0.cod == o1.cod}), let index2 = games.firstIndex(where: {$0.cod == o2.cod}) {
        return index1 < index2
    }
    return false
}

// Add missing games
for game in games {
    if !otGames.contains(where: {$0.cod == game.cod}) {
        otGames.append(OtGame(cod: game.cod, sor: game.des))
    }
}
```

Note that this sort has very bad performances, I suggest you to find a different data structure or solution to prevent this computation.